# How to use API response in multithreading Python

Tags: python, multithreading, api, rest, queue

So, I'm trying to write a queue on Python for load testing and I'm stuck. What I have:

- **Rest API** with authentication;
- **POST route** for sending a request;
- **requests** package for sending requests
- **Array with users email** that also contains their user_id.

When I passed the authentication I got a UserID and access_token. I can save it in a dictionary or a list, but then I need to use it for sending requests: user_id need for route, access_token for checksum calculation. But I don't see any variants for using these cases. I thought about two **for** loops, but I need a way to save access_token and user_id for all of my users in the dictionary and use it. And I'm not sure about this case, too.

I tried to do it in multithreading. For example:

```
q = queue.Queue()

def run_with_queue_api_authorize():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as pool:
        auth = [pool.submit(ApiAuthorization.get_token_generated, email) for email in ApiVariables.users]
        for r in concurrent.futures.as_completed(auth):
            q.put(r)
    print(q.qsize())
    return q

def run_with_queue_send_activity():
    start_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    run_with_queue_api_authorize()
    end_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    print(f"Execution time for auth:{end_time - start_time}, start time is {start_time}, end_time is {end_time}")
    time.sleep(10)
    start_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as pool:
        while not q.empty():
            task = q.get()
            new_try = [pool.submit(MultiQueue.multi_post_user_activity, task if task.done())]
            if q.empty():
                break
    end_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    print(f"Execution time for post user activity:{end_time - start_time}, start time is {start_time}, end_time is {end_time}")
```

When I use this code I can send my test data but for one user in the 3000 of threads. And it'll be failed for 2999 threads. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I tried to create a queue with **threading** package. It finishes immediately without any information. And I think that the solution with ThreadPoolExecutor is more reliable and most possible.

I can take a user_id from a special array but I need to get an access_token for this user. It doesn't look as a work case.

Why do I need it? Cause I need to get a count of requests in the second. But when I do authorization in the threads, I also send data at the same time asynchronously. And the total time for my tests will be counting with the time of authorization.

How can I resolved this problem? I've seen some videos about multithreading but it doesn't work for me. And I read a lot of information about the subject. But I can't apply it for my case.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: It looks as though your authorisation tokens are not correlated with the users. Also, you don't need a queue for this. You're multithreading and Python lists are thread-safe so just use a list. It appears that MultiQueue.multi_post_user_activity gets an authorisation token as its only input parameter but doesn't know which user it relates to unless ApiAuthorization.get_token_generated is building some object that contains both

Comment: @OldBill Thank you. I made a list with user_id and it helps. It's strange, I tried to append API response to list, but it doesn't work. But now it looks as a work solution.